# How to use VSCODE or PyCharm to work over SSH with requirement to raise permissions?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, visual-studio-code, pycharm

I have a puzzling dilemma. In using VSCode and Pycharm, I cannot discover how to SSH to a server, but THEN I have to sudo su  to become a certain user that has permission to write files to the server.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Paramiko` module can help you, which is a Python implementation of the SSHv2 protocol,

providing both client and server functionality.

> Reference: [paramiko_docs](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/)

and function `SSHClient()` is to connect a server.

but python don't have `paramiko` in default, install by `pip install paramiko` manually.